# How to use dates in xlim in matplotlib 3.2.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to set the x limits for my graph. I have the time array in datetime64[D] format. The plot takes in that array as the x axis however I am unable to modify using **plt.xlim( )** in matplotlib 3.2.1 and it gives an error. If I pass two date strings in the matplotlib 2.0.0 it works perfectly. Could you please tell me how to do the same for the newer version?

I have attached the trouble causing part of the code

```
time_stamp = np.arange('2020-02-24', '2020-05-13', dtype='datetime64[D]')

plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))

ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.plot(time_stamp, df_us['positive'], color='red')
ax1.plot(time_stamp, df_in['positive'], color='blue')
ax1.plot(time_stamp, df_it['positive'], color='green')

ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2, sharey=ax1, sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot(time_stamp, df_us['death'], color='lightcoral')
ax2.plot(time_stamp, df_in['death'], color='lightskyblue')
ax2.plot(time_stamp, df_it['death'], color='lightgreen')

plt.yscale(value="log")
plt.ylim(1, 1e7)
plt.xlim('2020-02-24','2020-05-12')

x_ticks = np.arange('2020-02-25', '2020-05-15', 10, dtype='datetime64[D]')
x_labels = ['25 Feb', '06 Mar', '16 Mar', '26 Mar', '05 Apr', '15 Apr', '25 Apr', '05 May']
plt.xticks(x_ticks, x_labels)
```

[Plot Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUVad.png)

You can see the result in the link above. `plt.xlim('2020-02-24','2020-05-12')` works great in 2.0.0

However when I run the same in 3.2.1 I get the following error message:

> matplotlib.units.ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: '2020-02-24'

Thanks in advance for you help!